# Cannot change color of button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am not able to change the color of the button using fg and bg. I get this error: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fg"`

```
_scrape_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Scrape!', command=save, fg='blue')
_scrape_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(N,E), pady=2)

_compress_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Compress!', command=compress)
_compress_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)
```

Comment: I might be missing something but in the code you've provided there is no setting of colour whatsoever. Please provide the code where you are actually doing that.

Comment: @rbaleksandar The OP most probably tried to put it as a parameter in the `ttk.Button` function, but got an error. So removed it and probably presented the code that was working. I will propose an edit to change it which would give an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are using `ttk.Button` instead of `tk.Button`. The options such as `fg`, `bg` are [not supported by ttk](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html). Instead you will have to use `Style` option and configure it as you require. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", foreground="blue", background="orange")

myButton = ttk.Button(text="Scrape", style="TButton")
myButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]